# c++ cant resolve variable BOOST_FOREACH

Tags: c++, boost, clion

Im trying to use the Boost library, I copied the entire boost folder except for the docs, libs, more, status, tools folders.

When I try to use the code block below, my compiler can't identify 2 things.

```
vector<string>* read(string & filename)
{


 // populate tree structure pt
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    read_xml(filename, pt);
    ptree tree;

vector<string> *ans = new vector<string>();

BOOST_FOREACH( ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("computer"))
{
    string name = v.first.get<string>("name");
    string OS = v.first.get<string>("OS");

    ans->push_back(name);
    ans->push_back(OS);
}

return ans;
}
```

1. 'BOOST_FOREACH' was not declared in this scope
2. Can't resolve struct member 'value_type'

I know the following include lines should be enough:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
```

If you need more info, please ask.
TIA

**EDIT**

after adding the include foreach.hpp, im getting:

[image: this issue]

Comment: Interesting screenshot you got there. Looks like your IDE configs are out of whack. Does it compile, though?

Comment: its not compiling..dont know why

Comment: @sehe please check regarding the new image

Comment: did you set properly the include paths? You can access other boost class/templates/whathever?

Comment: @Jepessen ye, i fixed them..ill edit my question

Comment: @OriRefael You're getting there. Sadly I don't see what causes that message. Version of compilers/libraries? Makefile?

Comment: @sehe ok, its working now..even though im getting this error...its compiling and running, Thanks alot

Comment: That's what I was getting at when I asked my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619192/c-cant-resolve-variable-boost-foreach?noredirect=1#comment55013469_33619192) here  :) So your IDE config is stiull cofnused, but at least you can make some other progress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know the following include lines should be enough:

Clearly they're not. Add

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
```

Fixed code:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f9a8fc4aea596f)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> read(std::string & filename)
{
    // populate tree structure pt
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;

    ptree pt;
    read_xml(filename, pt);
    ptree tree;

    std::vector<std::string> ans;

    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("computer"))
    {
        std::string name = v.second.get<std::string>("name");
        std::string OS   = v.second.get<std::string>("OS");

        ans.push_back(name);
        ans.push_back(OS);
    }

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: this file does not exists, only foreach.hpp and foreach_fwd.hpp

Comment: Already included the mandatory live sample: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f9a8fc4aea596f

Comment: if i do this i get like 30 errors when i hover the line..
something like "error after macro substitution: cant resolve namespace member..."

Comment: Show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I did and you can *see* it works. For one thing, fix your include paths. The `<../includes` thing doesn't make a lot of sense and will certainly **not** allow boost to find its own headers.

Comment: <raises brow/> why would you use /that/. I'm mildly amused with the speed at which you retort "everything doesn't work". Even to the point of pointing out the correct header name if I made a typo. Why don't you _fix that_ then?

Comment: ok, you are right, fixed the include stuff. still getting the error i added in the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94651/discussion-between-sehe-and-ori-refael).

Comment: ok, last question and im good to go, do you what might causing those errors i provided?

Comment: Yes, replied in chat. Your IDE config/Makefile seems out of whack. Use proper include paths at a minimum. Chances are, thing will unconfuse themselves. Optionally post your Makefile as well.

Comment: `#include <boost/foreach.hpp>`